# What do the Bessel & Brett, Buser & Kurucz and Cousins filters evolution with time tell us?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, spectroscopy, galaxies, wavelength

I have been studying different filters to observe galaxies and I'm not sure I completely understand what information one can take from, in particular, the evolution of difference of intensity in the U-V, R-K and J-K.

U,V - Buser & Kurucz (1978) filters
J,K - Bessel & Brett (1988) filters
R   - Cousins filters (Bessel 1990)

What information do these 3 intensity differences tell us about a galaxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U-V$, $J-K$ etc. are colours, not intensities, and they are measured in units of astronomical magnitudes.

The magnitude system is a logarithmic scale, whereby a factor of 100 brighter corresponds to 5 magnitudes *smaller*.

A colour is the *difference* between two flux measurements (in magnitudes) taken at different wavelengths through different filters and thus corresponds to a flux *ratio* between those wavelengths.

For example, the flux ratio between $U$ (near ultraviolet) and $V$ (visible/green) parts of the spectrum is calculated from

$$U - V =-2.5\log_{10}\left(\frac{f_U}{f_V}\right)$$
In general, colours are specified in terms of a bluer filter minus a redder filter. Because a bigger magnitude means a lower flux, then a bigger colour value means a larger flux ratio between the redder and bluer parts of the spectrum of the galaxy.

Comment: I got some insights from your comment but am still a little confused, if I have a U-V absolute magnitude of -1 what does it mean?